# randomForest regression with binary predictors

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a database with 8 binary predictors (yes/no) and a numerical outcome. I want to find out which combination of predictors is the best for predicting my outcome, but R's randomForest doesn't like binary predictors: I get NEGATIVE variance explained, and errors when trying to use 'importance' to rate the predictors.

**My code:**

```r
library(randomForest)
#binary predictors
print_size <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0) 
mid_ridge <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0)
classification <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0)
ridge_thickness <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
delta_center_distance <- c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1)
double_loop_size <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
whorl_length <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
loop_angle <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1)
#numeric result
LR <- c(44,42,34,20,19,11,9)
pred <- cbind(print_size, mid_ridge, classification, ridge_thickness,
              delta_center_distance, double_loop_size, 
              whorl_length, loop_angle, LR)
output.forest <- randomForest(LR ~ ., ntree=1000,data = pred, importance=TRUE)
print(importance(output.forest,type = 1))
```

**Results:**

```r
Mean of squared residuals: 210.327
% Var explained: -18.57
```

**Error**

> Error in UseMethod("importance") :    no applicable method for
>   'importance' applied to an object of class "c('standardGeneric',
>   'genericFunction', 'function', 'OptionalFunction', 'PossibleMethod',
>   'optionalMethod')"

Comment: You really don't have enough data to be doing a random forest

Comment: I would love suggestions on what CAN be done with this dataset!

Comment: You said you want to find out which combination of predictors can best explain your outcome.  You have seven data points and eight features with you. You need to have way more (atleast >1000) data points for something like randomforest to work well. A linear regression is your best best, but for that too, you have too many features. First cut down some features. For ex, double_loop_size and whorl_length are identical. Also `classification` is always 1-whorl_length; Keep only 1 of those. Cut down features to max 2-3 and check for p-val and coefficients.